# ARRAY_LITERAL error occuring when combining multiple IMPORTHTML functions together, even though all of the imports individually work

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas

So in working on this database, I'm running into an issue where most of the time I try to import data into my sheet, I'm running into the following error, "In ARRAY_LITERAL, an Array Literal was missing values for one or more rows." Here is the code being used:

`={IMPORTHTML(C1, "table", 20);IMPORTHTML(D1, "table", 20);IMPORTHTML(E1, "table", 20);IMPORTHTML(F1, "table", 20);IMPORTHTML(G1, "table", 20);IMPORTHTML(H1, "table", 20);IMPORTHTML(I1, "table", 20);IMPORTHTML(J1, "table", 20);IMPORTHTML(K1, "table", 20);IMPORTHTML(L1, "table", 20);IMPORTHTML(M1, "table", 20);IMPORTHTML(N1, "table", 20);IMPORTHTML(O1, "table", 20);IMPORTHTML(P1, "table", 20);IMPORTHTML(Q1, "table", 20);IMPORTHTML(R1, "table", 20);IMPORTHTML(S1, "table", 20);IMPORTHTML(T1, "table", 20);IMPORTHTML(U1, "table", 20);IMPORTHTML(V1, "table", 20);IMPORTHTML(W1, "table", 20);IMPORTHTML(X1, "table", 20);IMPORTHTML(Y1, "table", 20);IMPORTHTML(Z1, "table", 20);IMPORTHTML(AA1, "table", 20);IMPORTHTML(AB1, "table", 20);IMPORTHTML(AC1, "table", 20);IMPORTHTML(AD1, "table", 20);IMPORTHTML(AE1, "table", 20);IMPORTHTML(AF1, "table", 20);IMPORTHTML(AG1, "table", 20);IMPORTHTML(AH1, "table", 20)}`

From what I can tell, this usually results from one of the imports not working, however, I have both seen the database work (inconsitently) using this same formula, and the indvidual links I'm pulling from all work, all are the same format, and pull the same way. Is there a way that I can get this to work more conistently and not be constantly dealing with this error?

Answer (score 0):

*Use `vstack()` as such & you'll be able to see n' troubleshoot easily which of the table(s) among the whole cluster are being troublesome...*

```
=vstack(IMPORTHTML(C1, "table", 20),IMPORTHTML(D1, "table", 20),IMPORTHTML(E1, "table", 20),IMPORTHTML(F1, "table", 20))
```